# Enter the US with pending H1-B petition (company transfer)

Tags: usa, working-visas

I am a German citizen currently in the US with an approved H1-B visa for employer "A". I would like to travel to Germany for a week while employed for company "A".

*The catch*: I currently I have a **pending** H1-B petition for an H1-B transfer to a new employer "B". Has anyone re-entered the US with a pending petition while working for "A" and can share his or her experience?

Comment: How could this possibly be a  problem?

Comment: Surely you'll still be entering on your original H1-B for company A? The pending H!-B for company B shouldn't matter if you still work for company A